# Override margin in Separator Component of Fluent UI using React

Tags: css, reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I'm trying to override the margin attribute of a Separator component using Microsoft's Fluent UI using React.  The top-margin appears to default to 15px and I would like it to be less than that.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Problem pic]

The beige color section above is defaulting to 15px and I'd like to shrink it but I can't seem to find the correct css to do so.

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
  const separatorStyles = {
    root: [
      {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        selectors: {
          '::before': {
            background: 'black',
            top: '0px'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stack verticalAlign="center" verticalFill gap={15}>
        <Component1/>
        <Separator styles={separatorStyles} />
        <Component2 />
      </Stack>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried placing the `margin: 0` where it currently is at the root level and also nested below the `::before` but neither have worked.

The only other potential clue I have comes from an inspection of the styles in Chrome's DevTools which yields:

[image]

Any ideas would truly be appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `15px` actually came from the `gap` prop that was passed to the `Stack` component. It takes care of adding that css class to children elements to ensure the proper margins exist.

I believe removing it altogether should solve your concern, such as in this example ([link to working code](https://codepen.io/jdh-msft/pen/ExPxGRz?editors=0010)):

```jsx
<Stack verticalAlign="center" verticalFill>
        <button>Button1</button>
        <Separator>no margin</Separator>
        <button>Button2</button>
        <Separator />
        <button>Button3</button>
      </Stack>
```

However, it is worth noting that the `Separator` expects to render some text, so you might have trouble getting it to be the exact height you want (as font-size is a concern for the Separator). If that's the case, you might be better off just making your own control to render a 1px line with a simple `div` or `span`.

Comment: Excellent.  I should've realized that the 15 in the `Stack` component was related to the 15 I was seeing in the DevTools; that's embarrassing.  I didn't realize that it actually affected the _child_ components so directly.  This is good to know.  Thanks for the detailed answer and codepen example...and welcome to Stack Overflow @JD Huntington!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can you use this approach with styled-component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Separator} from '@fluentui/react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledSeparator = styled(Separator)`
    &::before {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    div {
        //any styles for separator-content
    }
`

export const Divider = ({children}) => {
    return <StyledSeparator>{children}</StyledSeparator>
}
```